# Add custom colors and tintColor to Toolbar using Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, toolbar

I am currently making a project, where I needed to add custom color to toolbar using Swift. I was able to add custom color to navigation bar but I am unable to add customization like navigation bar to toolbar. Is there anything else I am missing? I have researched a lot in StackOverflow about adding the tint color and text color to toolbar but I was not able to do so yet..

My code that customizes the navigation bar is as follows:

```
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

**For example:** If you use email app on iOS devices, you will see toolbar at the bottom of the screen, where Apple have added "Compose Message" icon. I want to customize this toolbar like I am currently doing for Navigation bar above. Any examples will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need change `UIToolBar` background image. The image same the color you want to set for your toolbar. See below code.

```
self.toolBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "your-image-name"), forToolbarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
//self.toolBar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .Any)
```

UPDATED: In Apple doc.

> Use these methods to set and access custom background images for toolbars.
>             Default is nil. When non-nil the image will be used instead of the system image for toolbars in the
>        specified position.
>             For the barMetrics argument, UIBarMetricsDefault is the fallback.
>
> DISCUSSION: Interdependence of barStyle, tintColor, backgroundImage.
>        When barStyle or tintColor is set as well as the bar's background image,
>        the bar buttons (unless otherwise customized) will inherit the underlying
>        barStyle or tintColor.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @longpham. I tried your suggestion but I have received error regarding "View Controller does not have a member named 'toolbar'". Looks like "toolbarItems" is a part of ViewController. Am I missing anything? Thanks for your suggestions...

Comment: @alfresco_developer It's the toolbar which you want to custom color.

Answer (score 0):

Change your nav variable from self.navigationController?.navigationBar to self.navigationItem. That is the one you want to customize.

Comment: Thanks @Ted Huinink, I tried your suggestion above. After modifying from self.navigationController?.navigationBar to self.navigationItem, I start receiving "UINavigationItem does not have a member named bar style". it shows this error for tint color and titleTextAttributes as well.. 
Am I missing something, can you show a sample code on doing your procedure?